# ArrayStoreException when calling stored procedure using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures

I get ArrayStoreException when calling stored procedure using Hibernate.

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:389)
at org.hibernate.util.ArrayHelper.toTypeArray(ArrayHelper.java:99)
at 
org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.typeArray(AbstractQueryImpl.java:855)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.getQueryParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:863)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.getQueryParameters(SQLQueryImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175)
```

**Here are the steps:-**

Java code call:-

```
Query query = hibernatesession.getNamedQuery("getEmployeeById");
query.setParameter(1, 12);
query.list();
```

SQL query:-

```
<sql-query name="getEmployeeById" callable="true">  
    {call sp_GetEmployeeById(?,?)}
</sql-query>
```

Stored Procedure is given below:-

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp_GetEmployeeById(employee_result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, eeId IN NUMBER) 
AS 
BEGIN

  OPEN employee_result FOR

  select * from employee where id = eeId;

END;
```

Has anyone resolved this issue?